# Large extra white space at the end of the table Bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap-4

The table has large extra white space at the end after all the columns but within the table border I have tried using the width , whitespace properties but they are not working. How I can remove the white space. I added the borders around card card-body and table to better understand the borders. I think it is an issue with the table, but cannot figure out the solution.
The white space is at the end , something like this
[image]

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card" style="border: 1px solid red;">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Employee List</h3>
                        <a asp-action="CreateEmployee" asp-controller="Employee" style="float:right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Add Employee"><i class="fas fa-plus" style="float:right; color:#b60962" ;></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.card-header-->
                    <!--form start-->
                    <div class="card-body" style="border : 1px solid green ">
                        <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover" style="border: 1px solid purple; white-space:nowrap;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="d-flex">
                                    <th>

                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Name
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Department
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Job Title
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Status
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Manager
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Email
                                    </th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var employee in Model)
                                {
                                    var photoPath = "";
                                    if (employee.EmployeePersonalDetails == null)
                                    {

                                        photoPath = "~/dist/img/avatar.png";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        photoPath = "~/dist/img/" + employee.EmployeePersonalDetails.PhotoPath;
                                    }
                                    <tr  class="d-flex align-content-center">
                                        <td>
                                            <img class="listImg" src="@photoPath" asp-append-version="true" alt="Emp Photo" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a asp-controller="Employee" asp-action="EmployeeOfficialDetails" asp-route-id="@employee.Id">@employee.FullName</a>

                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @employee.Department.Name
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @employee.JobTitle
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @employee.Status
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @employee.Manager
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @employee.Email
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                }

                            </tbody>


                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Could you please add your css?

Comment: there are no cutsom css for it as I am using a template. The error was fixed by adding a <div class= table-responsive> wrapping around table , instead of using it with the table tag